# opening a bash in second terminal

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

Im pretty new to bash and want to open a second bash script on a second terminal.

but for some reason im not able to doe this. 
Im using gnome-terminal and ive already set my preference to "hold terminal open"
if i just type in the terminal: 
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=shit -e "./Test.sh"
I get an error that says:
The child process exited normally with status 0 (and sometimes 2)

The test bash script is one line that says:
echo "hoi"

If anyone has the answer please let me know
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`The child process exited normally with status 0` is not an error message. It indicates everything went well in your script.

When `hold terminal open` is selected, this message will appear as a pop-up on the top of the new window when a command exits. Your output is simply too short for you to see under the pop-up message. If you add more lines to your output you should be able to see something.